# Using interfaces in java

Tags: java

Suppose there in an interface Displaceable and a class Circle which implements Displaceable. Displaceable has a method named move() which of course is implemented in Circle.

What would happen in the following scenario?

```
Circle a =  new Circle(..);
Displaceable b = a;
b.move()
```

Would the object refer to the Circle's move method?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, b.move() would be the same as calling a.move() in your scenario. This is [polymorphism](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) in action.

Comment: It's also called "dynamic dispatch"

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

`Displaceable b` says what *can* be done to *b*. The compiler can (and does) check whether that method is available on that type (Displaceable) at compile time.

*How* this is done is not necessarily clear at compile time. It's up to the implementation, at run-time, to just do it (move).

At compile time, the promise (I can move!) is checked. At runtime, the code has to prove that it really can :)

Even if `Displaceable` were a **class** and not an interface, and implemented `move` itself, the actual `move` called run-time would still be the implementation (if that implementation, `Circle`, would have overridden the `Displaceable` implementation).

The only time there is a compile-time binding of a call (to e.g. `move`) to the actual  implementation is when a method is defined as being static. That's also why static methods can't be defined in interfaces, as they don't hold implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, absolutely.

Its the same thing as doing this

```
void move(Displaceable b){
    b.move();
}

//somewhere else
move (new Circle(args));

move (new Square(args));

move (new Triangle(args));
```

If you think about it, its equivalent to have an abstract superclass Figure

```
public abstract class Figure{
     public abstract move();
}
//Circle extends Figure;

Figure f = new Circle(args);

f.move();
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Cool, isn't it? That's the beauty of polymorphism.

For the sake of completeness, I should add that if `Circle` extends some other class that has a `move()` method, it's possible that the method that gets called isn't defined in `Circle`, but some superclass.

In general, though, you've got the right idea.